# Switching out object based on data changing in Vue (with Vuex)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuex, watch

I am trying to switch out data that I have in a component based on what is clicked on in a tabs list on the top of my component page. The data comes from a Vuex data store. From testing the Vuex data store, everything seems to be working fine. I have dummy data in the data store that seems to be okay in my Vue Chrome dev tools plugin.

When I structure my component as I have it below and try to load the page, the console is complaining `Cannot read property 'amount' of undefined`. I'm assuming that this is because the data is loaded before the computed properties are in Vue.

I feel like I am overthinking this, but my goal is to switch out the data being displayed when one of my tabs is clicked. I **could** create a component for each tab and just call it a day, but I feel like that would be extremely repetitive.

---

**What I have Tried**

-Tried to replace the data's `currentObj: this.obj1` with `currentObj: {}`. Same error.

-Tried to move the `currentObj` data property to a computed property. When I do this, the page loads, but I still get the same error and when I click on the tabs, my data does not update.

---

Any idea how I can switch out the data in `currentObj` in my component?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab-title" v-on:click="tabSelection = 'tab1'">Tab 1</li>
      <li class="tab-title" v-on:click="tabSelection = 'tab2'">Tab 2</li>
      <li class="tab-title" v-on:click="tabSelection = 'tab3'">Tab 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div>{{ currentObj.amount }}</div>
  </div>
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      tabSelection: 'tab1',
      currentObj: this.obj1
    }
  },
  watch: {
    tabSelection: function(oldTabSelection, newTabSelection) {
      switch (newTabSelection) {
        case 'tab1':
          this.currentObj = this.obj1;
          break;
        case 'tab2':
          this.currentObj = this.obj2;
          break;
        case 'tab3':
          this.currentObj = this.obj3;
          break;
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    obj1: function() {
      return this.$store.getters.obj1;
    },
    obj2: function() {
      return this.$store.getters.obj2;
    },
    obj3: function() {
      return this.$store.getters.obj3;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you change your template. Try use safe navegation:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <div>{{ currentObj && currentObj.amount }}</div>
  </div>
<template>
```

Or

```html
<template>
  <div>
    ...
    <div v-if="currentObj">{{ currentObj.amount }}</div>
  </div>
<template>
```

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please accept this answer and this will help others people. [How to accept an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) - [Why accept an answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `currentObj` is undefined at some point and this isn't expected. The symptom can be treated like another answer shows, it can be useful if `obj1`, etc. can be missing in the store. This can only happen if `obj1`, etc. are undefined at the time when a tab is clicked:

> Tried to replace the data's currentObj: this.obj1 with currentObj: {}. Same error.

Even if  `obj1`, etc. are available in store, `obj1` computed property isn't available in `data` because component instance hasn't been created yet at this moment because it requires data to be created. `data` runs between `beforeCreate` and `created` hooks.

A workaround would be to call a getter:

```
currentObj: this.$options.computed.getNumbers.call(this)
```

Of course, this can cause problems if computed property uses other things that aren't available. A more correct workaround is to specify initial data explicitly:

```
currentObj: this.$store.getters.obj1
```

And a proper solution is to design the component the way it shouldn't be a problem. `tabSelection` watcher isn't needed, `currentObj` should be computed property and not data because it's *computed* from `tabSelection`:

```
  computed: {
    currentObj() {
      let obj;
      switch (this.tabSelection) {
        case 'tab1':
          obj = this.obj1;
          break;
        case 'tab2':
          obj = this.obj2;
          break;
        case 'tab3':
          obj = this.obj3;
          break;
      }
      return obj || { amount: 'No amount' } // in case missing objs are expected
    },
    ...
```